# Homepage of my site stuck as woocommerce shop

Tags: woocommerce

My site had a nice home page but when I was installing woocommerce and setting it up, I was asked to store store as the homepage and I did. Now, when I want to change the home page back to how it was, it is showing me my woocommerce shop as the homepage and any effort change that is futile. How can I change this please?

Comment: try googling 'wordpress set homepage'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to say, can you provide some more information like the theme and wordpress version? Generally speaking you should be able to set the Homepage in your Admin area under settings -> read. One thing to check would be to permanent delete the pages in the trash section and flush your permalinks by saving the permalink structure under settings -> permalinks. And if you haven’t done so yet a de-activation and activation of the theme and or woocommerce could help aswell...

Comment: Permanent delete the pages in the trash section and flush your permalinks by saving the permalink structure under settings -> permalinks ... I have not done this. Let me do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I visit the root url of my page, I am getting an error message, page not found' even after setting the page I want to be the static homepage.

Comment: Just to provide more information, this happened when configuring woocommerce and I allow store to be the homepage instead of my home page. When I tried to reverse this, it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Go to APPEARANCE > CUSTOMIZE > Homepage Settings
Ensure that you have selected the option: Your homepage displays A STATIC PAGE
Now look at the homepage dropdown just underneath that option.
Woocommerce has created a page on your webiste and named it Homepage
You need to select a different page in the dropdown for your homepage.
You can also delete 'Homepage' in the PAGES section of your wordpress install